# Adjusting anchor offsets on new page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, pageload

I've got a page that has multiple anchors to scroll to, when I scroll to them on the page itself using the nav at the top the nav scrolls to the correct place.

If I was to load the page at the same anchor in a different page it loads it with the nav covering the heading.

Is there any way to set an adjust the page's view for the anchor offset when the page loads, so that the nav doesn't cover the headings using jQuery?

```
<div class="section material-item" id="c-c">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**1.You can set the offsets to absolute position so that they may not move as the content in different pages change**

**2.Take the offsets of the achor tags relative to width/height of any element you are using anchor tag in between**.